# How to detect the unknown object stealing a specific shortcut?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a very complex Delphi 10.4.2 VCL Application, an unknown control or component seems to "steal" the `CTRL+A` shortcut. In an attempt to detect the object stealing the shortcut, I try using the `TApplicationEvents.OnShortCut` event handler:

```
procedure TformMain.ApplicationEvents1ShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  case Msg.CharCode of      
    VK_A:
      begin
        //CodeSite.Send('TformMain.ApplicationEvents1ShortCut: ', ???);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Can this event handler be used to detect the "thief", or which method would you suggest?

Comment: Why not searching all .PAS files for the text `ctrl` or `ssCtrl`?

Comment: @AmigoJack: That will miss a very large number of all possible scenarios, for instance, when you have a `TAction` with its `Shortcut` set to Ctrl+A. That's stored (utterly numerically) in the DFM.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That's true: The Action's `CTRL+A` shortcut is stored in the DFM as `ShortCut = 16449`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to implement shortcuts, so there might not be a single quick approach that can catch them all. But the following should cover many (if not most) cases.

All background knowledge you need can be found in Peter Below’s  [A Key’s Odyssey](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447).

First, if you know that some code is executed as a result of this shortcut, you can put a breakpoint in this code and the call stack will likely tell you all you need to know.

For instance, if I create a new VCL application, add a `TActionList`, and a `TAction` with shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and an `OnExecute` handler which calls the `CreateFrog` procedure, I can put a breakpoint in this procedure, and I get the following call stack:

[image: Call stack]

Here we immediately see that `CreateFrog` was called due to an action named `aTest` with a matching shortcut. In fact, if you go down all the way down to `TControl.WndProc` (say) you can even see that the `T` (`84`) key was depressed (`CN_KEYDOWN = 48384`):

[image: Screenshot of local variables]

If you don't have any nice place to put a breakpoint, you can put a conditional breakpoint in `TControl.WndProc` with condition `(Message.Msg = CN_KEYDOWN) and (Message.WParam = 84)`:

[image: Screenshot of Source Breakpoint Properties dialog box]

Then, if you run the app and trigger the shortcut, you will be able to step through the source code and see what happens.

Comment: The thief was a forgotten `TAction` with the Shortcut `CTRL+A`!